# Validate Additional parameters in Requestbody for Springboot request and throw 400

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-validator, spring-boot-starter, javax-validation

```
@Data
public class Employee{
@NotNull
@NotBlank
private string id;

@NotNull
@NotBlank
private string name;
}

@RestController
@Validated
class EmployeeController{

@postMapping(consumes="json", produces="json")
public ResponseEntity getEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody Employee){
 return response;
}
```

}

Added Exceptional Handler with MethodArgumentNotvalidException.

positive Validation works fine, Whenever we check with id & name.

```
Expectation is, if we add any additional parameters along with id and name, it should throw the 400
```

sample  input :
{
"abc":"xyz",
"id":"09e240",
"name":"Billa"
}

```
Expected Output : 400 bad request
```

Answer (score 1):

The validation doesn't occur until after the deserialization into the `Employee` object has occurred; therefore, I don't believe you can do this with the validation API.

What you want to do is force the deserialization to fail on unknown properties.  Create a bean of type `ObjectMapper` and configure it to fail deserialization when it encounters unknown properties.

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);

    return objectMapper;
}
```

This will throw an `UnrecognizedPropertyException`, then you can use ControllerAdvice to map this to a 400.  By the way, I suspect that you have already created this bean somewhere as the default behavior for ObjectMapper is set to FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES -> true.

The controller advice to map the `UnrecognizedPropertyException` will look like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;


@ControllerAdvice
public class Advice {

    @ExceptionHandler(UnrecognizedPropertyException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleDeserializationErrors(UnrecognizedPropertyException unrecognizedPropertyException) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(unrecognizedPropertyException.getMessage());
    }
}
```